# Sometimes when I change or add some code it doesn't work unless I restart VS Code. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I change or add some code it doesn't work unless I restart VS Code. How do I fix this? I'm using Windows 11. It also does it on my other computer which is using Windows 10.

I also kill all the terminals at bottom right just in case (where there is powershell, python etc, sometimes 3 or 4). Usually it's just 1 python terminal.

Comment: uninstall then install

Comment: what do you mean by " it doesn't work"?

Comment: Sometimes when I change or add some code **it doesn't work**. _What does not work? Are you getting some errors when trying to compile code? Please provide more details.

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? Have you ensured the code is saved? You can use "ctrl+s" to save file

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, I mean the code don't give me the correct output. It comes up with different errors... I will make note of which errors come up.
When I restart the program, the output works.

Comment: @davibus Can you provide some examples to reproduce the problem